# PHP: Check if anything comes after given string in URL?

Tags: php

I need to create a an if statement that fires if there is something after a given string in the URL.

For example, if my string is 'Honda' I need to check if something appears after that word in the url, eg something like:

```
$brand = "honda";

if (url contains $brand . '/*'){
  // Do something.
}
```

Example urls could be:

- mysite.com/honda (which would fail the above)
- mysite.com/cars/honda (which would fail the above)
- mysite.com/honda/civic (which would pass the above)
- mysite.com/honda/accord (which would pass the above)

I know I can use `strpos()` to detect if the string is within the URL, but how can I detect if anything comes after that?

Comment: check the string length if it is greater then your string length you can fire you event.

Comment: you can also explode() with "honda" and check the lenght of the array return

Comment: Just check if it starts with "honda" but not equal to "honda".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression that looks for the `$brand` at the end of the string.

```
if (! preg_match("/{$brand}$/", $url)) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need to check if the `$brand` actually appears in the URL before running your end of string check:

```
if (strpos($brand, $url) !== false && ! preg_match("/{$brand}$/", $url)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give false positives? It would return false if there is something after _and_ if the string doesn't exist at all? Shouldn't it be if it starts with $brand and has at least something after?

Comment: None of the examples provided by OP asked about the value not being in the string. You could check for the existence too, if necessary.

Comment: In the OP's first sentence: "if statement that fires if there is something _after_ a given string in the URL"

Comment: The operative word being _after_. Not _if_ it appears and if it does, _after_. But I've edited my answer either way.